# How do I match a specific pattern and exclude specific sub-strings with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I match a specific pattern and exclude specific sub-strings with regex case insensitive

I am trying to write Regex for New Zealand address validation.
This is the valid character set which I want to capture case insensitive which includes **A** to **Z** numbers and letters hyphen "**-**" and forward slash "**/**" as well as Maori accented characters for Maori vowels **ā**, **ē**, **ī**, **ō**, **ū** and works.

```
....

var regex = /^[\/A-zĀ-ū0-9\s\,\''\-]*$/;

....
```

It needs to exclude the following sub-strings case insensitive, with or without spaces to be valid

**PO Box**

**Private Bag**

(tricky as both those sub-strings could include spaces or not and be upper or lower case depending on how the user types them)

and the string **must start with a number** to be valid

e.g.

This is invalid:

**Flat 1 311 Point Chevalier Road, Point Chevalier, Auckland 1022, New Zealand**

This is valid:

**1/311 Point Chevalier Road, Point Chevalier, Auckland 1022, New Zealand**

311/1 or 311-1 or 1-311 are all considered valid by NZ Postal Service.

example if this if statement is true considering the regex above then the address string is invalid:

```
// Allowed character set
var regex = /^[\/A-zĀ-ū0-9\s\,\''\-]*$/;

// Get the address string and convert to lowercase for evaluation pseudocode
var str = getValue().toLowerCase();

// Strip spaces 
str = str.replace(/\s/g, '');

// If the sub string "pobox" or sub string "privatebag" or string doesn't start with a number or doesn't match allowed character set address is invalid
if(str.includes("pobox") || str.includes("privatebag") || (str.match(/^\d/) == null) || (!regex.test(str))){

....
```

Thanks I really appreciate the input of the community and I know there are Regex gurus out there. I am trying to simplify this so I can use HTML5 form validation rather than a clunky JavaScript evaluation.

Comment: To require a digit as first chracter: `^\d` ... for disallowing some condition at certain points in your pattern eg a neg. [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) can be used. Together maybe something [like this demo](https://regex101.com/r/jh5OQR/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to first match the expressions you want to exclude and then regex with the allowed character set.

```
/^.*(po\s*box|private\s*bag).*$|^\d[\/a-zĀ-ū0-9\s\,\'\-]*$/i
```

By capturing the excluded patterns, you can check if group 1 has a value. If so, you know that the string should be skipped

```
var regex = /^.*(po\s*box|private\s*bag).*$|^\d[\/a-zĀ-ū0-9\s\,\'\-]*$/i;
var match = str.match(regex);

if (match && !match[1]) {
   // valid address
} else {
   // invalid address
}
```

#### See https://regex101.com/r/AiL6Dy/2

Comment: that is just awesome and works for every scenario except one requirement which is the string must start with a number. If I can tweak it to include that requirement it is perfect. e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/jeremy_tactical/ad71ey6k/4/

Comment: Hi Arnold, I am still a real noob when it comes to regex, how do I also check if the string starts with a number combined with your beautiful regex you wrote, I attempted `var regex = /^.*(po\s*box|private\s*bag).*$|^\d|^[\/a-zĀ-ū0-9\s\,\'\-]+$/i;` obviously wrong though.

Comment: @JeremyLeys I've updated regex. Now it says, start with a number followed by zero or more valid chars.  If you want the number followed by 1 or more valid chars, use `+` instead of `*`. Basically, that part is just regular regexp. Use regex101 to play around with it. It also shows an explanation.

Comment: Arnold thank you this is a brilliant solution, you are awesome.